# X11 from headless server to another X11 server

Tags: x11, x11-forwarding

I have an application running on a headless server. It is a web application but for a certain feature (debugging) it runs a swing based application. As the server is headless (I already set the **-Djava.awt.headless=true**) it throws an exception when starting it up...

I've tried installing Xvfb but that wouldn't solve my problem as Xvfb doesn't have a GUI output and I couldn't see the output.

So I want to redirect/forward the output of that server to another one (for instance my laptop) in order to see the swing application and debug it.

Is there any way of achieving it using the DISPLAY variable or anything else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an X-server running on your laptop, you could ssh into your server with enabled X-Forwarding in your SSH, it will automagically set your DISPLAY variable to something in lines of :10.0 and you can run your application with GUI being exported to your local X-server.

Otherwise if you want to set DISPLAY manually you would need to make sure that server can reach your laptop with a direct TCP connection on x-server port.

Answer (score 1):

You can either

1. Run Xvnc and connect to it using a VNC client
2. Run Xvfb together with x11vnc and connect to it using a VNC client (this is different from the above but the end result for you is the same; useful only if you already run Xvfb for some other reason)
3. Use ssh forwarding of X11 sessions (or a direct TCP connection) as per favoretti's answer

Options 1 or 2 are useful if you have Windows on your laptop and don't want to run an X11 server on it. You can use a Windows native VNC client then.

You can also RDP instead of VNC (X11rdp or xrdp on the X11 side and RDP client on the Windows side). This should give faster refresh rates but it's supposedly harder to set-up on the X11 side (I haven't done it personally). OTOH Windows has a built-in RDP client so you don't even have to install anything on the Windows side.

If you have X11 on your laptop, it's much easier to use option 3.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough "Rep" to comment on another user's answer, so my post is for the purpose of augmenting "favoretti"'s good answer.

If you a running a Windows PC, install the cygwin unix subsystem and install x-windows and ssh. If using OSX startup X11 or for Mavericks onward, install xQuartz.

Then as mentioned you can ssh into the target (headless) remote server and specify the -X flag to allow X traffic to come back over the wire

```
 ssh -l <user> -X -v <host>
```

You may or may not have to invoke the command

```
xhost +
```

to permit X traffic to flow back to your machine.